# Is executable file generated after compiling in C can be copied and run on any differnet OS(UNIX)?

Tags: c

I am a java programmer, but i have few things to be done in C. So, i started with a simple example as below. If i have compiled it and generate a executable file (hello), can i run the executable file (hello) in any unix platform without the original file (hello.c)? And also is there a way to read the data from executable file means, decompile the executable file to original file (hello.c)?

```
[oracle@oracleapps test]$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i,data =0;
for(i=1;i<=64;i+=1){
data = i*2;
printf("data=%d\n",data);
}
return 0;
}
```

To compile

```
gcc -Wall -W -Werror hello.c -o hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the resulting executable on platforms that are ABI-compatible with the one which you have compiled the executable for. ABI-compatibility basically means that the same physical processor architecture and OS-interfaces (plus calling convention) is used on two (possibly different) OSes. For example, you can run binaries compiled for Linux on a FreeBSD system (with the same processor type), because FreeBSD includes Linux ABI-compatibility. However, it may not be possible to run a binary on all other types of Unices, unless some hackery is done. For example, you can't run Mac OS X applications on linux, however [this guy has a solution](https://github.com/shinh/maloader) with which it's possible to use some OS X command line tools (including the GCC compiler itself) on Linux.

Reverse engineering: there are indeed decompilers which aim to generate C code from machine code, but they're not (yet) very powerful. The reason for this is they're by nature extremely hard to write. Machine code patterns have to be recognized, and even then you can't gather all the original info. For example, types of loops, comments and non-static local variable names and most of the types are all gone during the compilation process. For example, if you have a C source file like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("I is: %d\n", i); /* Write the value of I */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

a C decompiler may be able to reconstruct the following code:

```
int main(int _var1, void *_var2)
{
    int _var3 = 0;
    while (_var3 < 10)
    {
        printf("I is: %d\n", _var3);
        _var3 = _var3 + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But this would be a rather advanced decompiler, such as [this one.](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Hogan blame it on the decompiler :P

Comment: Quick!  Open a boomerang bug report!

Comment: Well, to be fair, going from the output you present to one very close to the input is just a matter of recognizing some simple conventions in the code (such as the desugaring of `for(init; cond; step)` to `init; while (cond) { ...; step; }` and loop variables being called `i`). Good decompilers only fall down for more complicated code.

Comment: @delnan that pattern can be decompiled in any way. There's nothing with which it could be decided whether it was a for or a while loop in the original source.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know, and it's important to point that out. But it's also important that the people writing decompilers aren't stupid (quite the contrary, in fact) so when in doubt they *won't* choose the least readable, un-idiomatic and unlikely rendering.

Comment: To be pedantic, BSD can not run 64-bit Linux binaries, only 32-bit ones.

Answer (score 1):

No ... each platform may have a different executable format requirements, different hardware architectures, different executable memory layouts determined by the linker, etc.  A compiled executable is "native" to it's currently compiled platform, not other platforms.  You can cross-compile for another architecture on your current machine though.

For instance, even though they may have many similarities, a compiled executable on Linux x86 is not guaranteed to run under BSD, depending on it's flavor (i.e., you could probably run it under FreeBSD but typically not OSX's Darwin version of BSD even thought both machines may have the same underlying hardware architecture).  You also couldn't compile something on a SGI MIPS machine running IRIX and run it on a Sun SPARC running Solaris.

Comment: You chose a bad example there, since you actually *can* run Linux binaries on some BSDs.

Comment: Okay, I clarified that portion of my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the executable on any platform.

You can run the executable on other machines (or this one) without the .c file.  If it is the same OS / Distro running on the same hardware.

You can use a de-compiler to disassembler to read the file and view it as assembly or C-- they won't look much like the original c file.

Answer (score 1):

The compiled file is pure machine code (plus some metadata), so it is self-sufficient in that it does not require the source files to be present. The downside? Machine code is both OS and platform-specific. By platform, we usually mean just roughly the CPU's instruction set, i.e. "x86" or "PowerPC", but some code compiled with certain compiler flags may require specific instruction set extensions. The OS dependence is caused not only by different formats for executable files (e.g. ELF as opposed to PE), but also by use of OS-specific services, or common OS services in an OS-specific manner (e.g. system calls). In addition to that, almost all nontrivial code depends on some libraries (a C runtime library at least), so you probably won't be able to run an executable without having the right libraries in compatible versions. So no your executable likely won't run on a 10 year old proprietary UNIX, and *may* not run on different Linux distributions (though with your program there's a good chance it does, because it likely only depends on `glibc`).

While machine code can be easily disassembled, the result is very low-level and useless to many people. Decompilation to C is almost always much harder, though there are attempts. The algorithms can be recovered, simply because they *have* to be encoded in the machine code *somehow*. Assuming you didn't compile for debugging, it will *never* recover comments, formatting, variable names, etc. so even a "perfect" decompiler would yield a different C file from the one you put in.

Answer (score 0):

With C programs, the program is tied to the environment it was compiled for (which is usually the same as the platform it was compiled on, unless you are cross-compiling).  You could copy something built for one version of Linux (and a particular hardware architecture) to another machine with the same archtecture running the same version of Linux, and you'll be fine.  You can often get away with running it on a related version of Linux.  But you won't get x86/64 code to run on a IA32 machine, nor on a PPC machine, nor on a SPARCmachine.  You can likely get IA32 code to run on an x86/64 machine, if the basic O/S is sufficiently similar.  And you may or may not be able to get something compiled for Debian to run under RedHat or vice versa; it depends on which libraries your program uses.

Java avoids this by having a platform-neutral byte code program that is compiled, and a platform specific JVM (JRE) to run it on each platform.  This WORM (Write Once, Run Many) behaviour was a key selling point for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run it on any unix `qemu` runs on. This is pretty comparable to java programs, which you can run on any unix the jvm runs on...